# Java package reference without changing the implemented application

Tags: java, encapsulation

I have a java JAR with a.b.c.Demo.class. This class is used my an application. Now, if I want change the package of Demo.class in the JAR and want my application should work without changing the package name??

Comment: If you change the package name of `Demo` class, e.g. from `a.b.c.Demo` to `x.y.z.Demo`, then any code using it will need to be changed too, mostly just the `import` statements they have.

Comment: Do you mean moving the class let's say from package `a.b.c` to package `d.e.f` without edit the package line in class `package a.b.c;` and without re-compiling? Do I have this right?

Comment: Yes your are correct

Answer (score 0):

Just change it in your IDE (`Right click -> Refractor -> Rename`), with the checkbox `update references` checked and it will update everywhere the name

Comment: I also know this option but I don't want to change the application code. Please, tell any option which will not make any change in the application.

Comment: Oh you can't change the class name if the jar is already packed as I know.
But before packaging your jar, you can change your class name, but it's not what you want, so, what is your goal to do that ?